# Disabling Star Rating on certain condition

Tags: jquery

I am using a simple [jQuery Star Rating plugin](http://irfandurmus.com/projects/jquery-star-rating-plugin/).

It works great: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/oaLz4zgb/)

This plugin best suits my requirement and has less code:

```
$(function() {                  // Start when document ready
    $('#star-rating').rating(); // Call the rating plugin
});
```

Only one thing is unclear for me: how can I disable this rating for some user (ex. unauthorized user)?

What I have tried is to disable input box, but it also doesn't work as I want - still anyone can rate.

Comment: Assuming people log in to use your site (to become 'authorised'), don't initialize the rating plug-in until/unless they're logged in. The plug-in itself has no customisation, except for a callback to submit the chosen rating.

Comment: @DavidThomas yes this is an idea but if don't initialize rating plugin it shows radio button not stars. :(

Comment: @Manwal : Are you setting any flag to check whether user is authorized or not?

Comment: Ya sure @Prateek i am setting a flag to check user is authorized or not

Comment: @DavidThomas is there is way to add parameter in plugin? like `$('#star-rating').rating({disable:'disable'});`

Comment: Not according to the documentation you linked to, no.

Comment: No @DavidThomas i am asking about, if i can add custom parameter like `disable` and modify jquery `rating.js` check when binding click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always disable the events which makes the rating work.
To imitate the disabled effect, you may want to change the css little bit.
Run this script after the plugin initialization.

`$('.stars').unbind();$('.stars .star').unbind();`

Comment: You can't tell me to accept it. I know what i am doing here. You need to explain side effects first

Comment: what i meant by side effect is, it will unbind **ALL** the events which is assigned (either by this plugin or by other plugins) to that elements. also other scripts can bind an event to that element after this unbind has happened. Hope i am clear.

Comment: also you dont have to be rude on anything. if this answer doesnt helped you then you dont have to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I am able to manage all side effects. Updated your answer removed unwanted this. Thanks